# Nautilus Script for multiple files (ffmpeg)

Tags: bash, scripting, ffmpeg, nautilus

I have little background in programming and need to create a batch to extract the audio of multiple video files. Execution is done through the context menu in Nautilus/Gnome Files, stored in Nautilus' scripts folder as a bash .sh.
The following code works for 1 file, but when selecting multiple files it doesn't. Could someone please help me modify the code to make it work.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$(echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | sed -e 's/\r//g')
FILENAME2=$(echo "$FILENAME" | cut -f 1 -d '.') 

    ffmpeg -i "${FILENAME}" -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 "${FILENAME2}".wav

    # finished message box
    zenity --info --title "Procesing completed" --text "${FILENAME2}.wav at 48kHz has been generated." --width=700
```

Comment: You should use `$FILENAME` and `$FILENAME2` as an array and iterate over each item of those arrays (both arrays should have the same length/number of items)

Comment: Btw, `FILENAME2=$(echo "$FILENAME" | cut -f 1 -d '.')` is removing all what you have after the `.`. So if you have `/path/to/file.mp4 /path/to/file2.mp4` using the `cut` you will get: `/path/to/file`

Comment: Thank you @EdgarMagallon. Could you link me please an example of how to implement $FILENAME as an array and iterate the command (ffmpeg) over the array's item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script, cannot test it with `ffmpeg` but it should work.

---

```bash
#!/bin/bash

{

readarray FILENAME <<< "$(echo -e "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | sed -e 's/\r//g')"

echo -e "Logs: $(date)\n" > ~/Desktop/data.txt

for file in "${FILENAME[@]}"; do
    
    file=$(echo "$file" | tr -d $'\n')
    echo "Current file: $file" >> ~/Desktop/data.txt
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 "${file%.*}.wav"
    zenity --info --title "Procesing completed" --text "${file%.*}.wav at 48kHz has been generated." --width=700
done


} 2>~/Desktop/ffmpeg.logs
```

---

The code above will print a message with `zenity` each time a `mp4` is processed. But if you want to display the message when all files are processed then you can use this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

{

readarray FILENAME <<< "$(echo -e "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | sed -e 's/\r//g')"

echo -e "Logs: $(date)\n" > ~/Desktop/data.txt

for file in "${FILENAME[@]}"; do
   
    file=$(echo "$file" | tr -d $'\n')
    echo "Current file: $file" >> ~/Desktop/data.txt
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 "${file%.*}.wav"
done

zenity --info --title "Procesing completed" --text "$( printf "%s.wav\n" "${FILENAME[@]%.*}") at 48kHz has been generated." --width=700

} 2>~/Desktop/ffmpeg.logs
```

---

I suggest you use this script. Because is able to detect what files failed and what were generated successfully:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

{

readarray FILENAME <<< "$(echo -e "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | sed -e 's/\r//g')"

echo -e "Logs: $(date)\n" > ~/Desktop/data.txt
okFiles=()
errFiles=()

for file in "${FILENAME[@]}"; do
    
    file=$(echo "$file" | tr -d $'\n')
    echo -e "\n===========================" >> ~/Desktop/data.txt
    echo "Current file: $file" >> ~/Desktop/data.txt
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 "${file%.*}.wav" && {
        okFiles+=("${file%.*}.wav")
        :
    } || {
        
        errFiles+=("${file%.*}.wav")
    }
done

if [[ ${#okFiles[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    zenity --info --title "Procesing completed" --text "$(printf '%s\n' ${okFiles[@]})\n at 48kHz have/has been generated." --width=700
fi

if [[ ${#errFiles[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    zenity --info --title "Error while processing some files" --text "Following files:\n$(printf "%s\n" "${errFiles[@]}")\ncould not be generated." --width=700
fi

} 2>~/Desktop/ffmpeg.logs
```

---

About:

```bash
{
  code
  code
} 2>~/Desktop/ffmpeg.logs
```

I used that to be able to detect what fails when you are processing every file. For example, if in some file `ffmpeg` throws an error you will be able to check the logs inside the path `~/Desktop/ffmpeg.logs`

Btw, if you want every file processed to be located on specific path and not where you call the script you can do something like this (before `readarray`):

```bash
{
  cd ~/Audios/path/to/dir #the path you want can be placed here
  readarray ...
  code
} 2>~/Desktop/ffmpeg.logs
```

Finally, you can notice that `FILENAME2` is no longer needed, because I use `"${file%.*}.wav"` instead (see [bash parameter expnasion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)).

Comment: For some strange reason the files can't be located. Maybe some quotation marks are missing? ffmpeg.logs: "No such file or directory". Data.txt shows the same file path, which is correct and corresponds to an existing file (defined by Nautilus' selection).

Comment: @Domingo can you provide what path(s) are being sent to the script? I tested my script with paths containing spaces and it worked well. I don't think that the quotation marks are the problem but please provide your path(s) to be sure.

Comment: I'm trying with an .mp4 on the desktop. data.txt shows: Current file: /home/chuma/Desktop/06.mp4. Last lines of the log are:
...
libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
/home/chuma/Desktop/06.mp4
: No such file or directory

Comment: @Domingo thanks! I tested and I know what's going on!

Comment: :) Tell me tell me!

Comment: @Domingo updated answer! The problem was with the paths, because at the end they had `\n` and therefore the script could not find them. The solution was to add this line: `file=$(echo "$file" | tr -d $'\n')`. I've provided a third and better solution to your script too.

Comment: It works like a charm!! Bless your Edgar, it looks much better with the new logs now also. I will try to adapt the code to other types of ffmpeg video transcodings but this is a solid base I can definitely reuse and adapt.

Comment: @Domingo Glad to know that :). It will be easier now to adapt the script as you want. I assume you can use `zenity` to provide the type of files available to convert your files. Good luck!